# How to link keywords in custom fields?

Tags: custom-field, linking

I have come across different WordPress plugins that will automatically link/hyperlink keywords--to external links--every time they appear throughout posts. Here's an explanation of what I mean:

**Site page 1 content:**

Georgio went to the store after he stopped by to see how Nichols was doing.

**Site page 2 content:**

The cat was afraid of Georgio and his dog.

**Site page 3 content:**

My best friend is not a friend of Nichols, who is the best friend of Georgio, but is a friend of Georgio.

**What I need done:**

On each page (1, 2, 3) and each time it appears on each page, I want "Georgio" to be linked to the same external website (like http://geethr33whiskers.net <---I just made that up), but without me having to manually link each "Georgio". I want to be able to link "Georgio" once and then automatically the other instances will be linked to the same external website.

On each page (1, 3) and each time it appears on each page, I want "Nichols" to be linked to the same external website (like http://www.nichols2zzz4wedding.com <---I just made that up), but without me having to manually link each "Nichols". I want to be able to link "Nichols" once and then automatically the other instances will be linked to the same external website. **END OF EXPLANATION**

Now back to what I was saying before the explanation... All the plugins that I've found are only linking the specific keywords found within the post_content area of the posts. My content is not found within the default WP post_content area, though. I am using the 'custom fields' feature of WP to enter the content for every one of my posts (I do this so I can have better control of where the content appears on the site). How do I get the plugins to look within the 'custom fields' for the keyword to link? Is there a 'custom fields' code I need to add to the plugin files?

Thanks.